# How to determine which type of a function from a union is being used?

Tags: typescript

```typescript
type TabWithSetIndex = (props: TabContentProps) => React.ReactElement;
type TabWithoutSetIndex = () => React.ReactElement;

interface ProjectCardProps {
  tabs: Array<{
    tabContent: TabWithSetIndex | TabWithoutSetIndex;
  }>;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwOoEtgAsDKFgEkB2AJhAB5QC8UAFGAE4D2YAzgFyyIDC9+wEPACg2YBKCgD4oAJQhwAxsAB00ucACiAGwgBbPsADcAKFCR2yNOnoBXYNjxFSFaqPITl8pTPkbtuwwZQ8ELQAZnLQgvQAVhDyHHC0hBHMUADeBlBQwIisUACCtLRwIAA8aRkZWQhcgTxs8GYYtgTEZAA+pqgYVjY4zaSGGQC+YoaDBkA)

How to validate whether `tabContent` is of type `TabWithSetIndex` or `TabWithoutSetIndex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options for you:

- Function `length` with a type predicate
- A discriminated union (with or without a type predicate)

#### Function `length` with a type predicate

You *can* do this with a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) like this:

```typescript
function isTabWithoutSetIndex(
    tabContent: TabWithSetIndex | TabWithoutSetIndex
): tabContent is TabWithoutSetIndex {
    return tabContent.length === 0;
}
```

(The [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property of a function is, roughly speaking, the number of declared formal parameters it has that don't have default values.)

Then, when you're looking at a specific `tab.tabContent`, you do:

```typescript
if (isTabWithoutSetIndex(tab.tabContent)) {
    // It's `TabWithoutSetIndex`
    tab.tabContent();
} else {
    // It's `TabWithSetIndex`
    tab.tabContent({x: "foo"});
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgeirgAUAbdJACwgYBMko5No4QwAM5DgAOwDmcGAE8wScrPlwAKigBGAYQhiYSXXRxghcALxwA3uTg24ADwBccITCjiJFAL4VFcpKo0AdWAYFgBlJBgASTEuOzM4AAowIyEnNS0dPQNUgEozAD5EYhgAOmR0GABRBiQQfRgKJX8M4NCIAFcYCOjYpHjzRPzTIoqMcpKauoafcT0oTGZ6HAArJAxNFCgOQwhjS2tbGA00uABBKCgUGQAeK1sH6Q1tXQb0oJDwyJi4uAAfALqNpsLo9H79CgPTwFLyUTAdMQYYA6ODCVqfTrdb59OyJY6ZV66d5Az5gnH-QHAzFkuK5Jz4l7ZeDCSkY0HY373WxEGAdKBiJ4EpmlWqSUJmUzmAAMsPIaB0LjgVTsKHAtQSyVSTl2aw2Wx2eUKBwefB4iXlYkV+LgEEwcBSeyEpXxQnyXMeqLtiTRH3a7N6cTxGmdzyyDVybsOHoeNDgURgAHITAADdF+rEB-rJqPRmz4kNChpDSHRzxwJAMIT+d25uCx+NJuCp31fTN2bO1o7Bhlh3SJCz2Jz4PgQfBwTy5Esezw5mcPHl8gViDoMBheChAA)

**That said**, I worry about using the function's `length`, since this is a perfectly valid `TabWithSetIndex` that has a `length` of `0`:

```
function thisIsATabWithSetIndex(...args[]) {
    // ...
}
```

...since rest parameters don't get count in `length`.

#### A discriminated union (with or without a type predicate)

To avoid using `length`, you can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions), like this:

```typescript
type TabWithSetIndex =
    ((props: TabContentProps) => React.ReactElement) &
    { __type__: "withSetIndex"; };
type TabWithoutSetIndex =
    (() => React.ReactElement) &
    { __type__: "withoutSetIndex" };
```

Then you'd have utility functions to set that `__type__` property callers would pass their functions through:

```typescript
function makeWithSetIndexFunction(
    fn: (props: TabContentProps) => React.ReactElement
): TabWithSetIndex {
    return Object.assign(fn, {__type__: "withSetIndex"}) as TabWithSetIndex;
}
function makeWithoutSetIndexFunction(
    fn: () => React.ReactElement
): TabWithoutSetIndex {
    return Object.assign(fn, {__type__: "withoutSetIndex"}) as TabWithoutSetIndex;
}
```

Then either just test `__type__` directly:

```typescript
if (tab.tabContent.__type__ === "withoutSetIndex") {
    // It's `TabWithoutSetIndex`
    tab.tabContent();
} else {
    // It's `TabWithSetIndex`
    tab.tabContent({x: "foo"});
}
```

...or use a type predicate that's more reliable now:

```typescript
function isTabWithoutSetIndex(
    tabContent: TabWithSetIndex | TabWithoutSetIndex
): tabContent is TabWithoutSetIndex {
    return tabContent.__type__ === "withoutSetIndex";
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-hPIVu7XQgm7ALQ6nIzG4-69QC7MmwxH02TM9ni6VqmWMBWmtXVZaAzvbU3Ii24O3OxVu6I+wOxMOLKP5C+P1dSXGc5xMHUOW3blyE8SgaFUJAXHcd5PUGOAOGAIgMH6BxyDQHQXDgGo7BQcB6gARjME40lRbEUXfBEkULIRT0bGw+B4JICLEIjFTgCBMDgWjjHKRVWMfckJSEhUNDEykciad0PkA9CfV9ScrQ1Ox8EKdipNsBCohgAByEwAANIK0+tzOOAyXXk10miSfIeQMzw4CQBghH8fT7KM0yLMgpdbPsslFUc-NdCSTpHAIPgICBWc3KkuDeWOZsnTgMRNgYBgvAoBCAFVREkaQWH8EBoCQABaIgGGADR6mkPxhKITC0BQPR8MI+ASLIsB6gAJmonM6KcBi4RgJjkQKYpJN4fhuN6l0BKEkShEciS-NsYAZMlOkQO02T1EixTdHyPS7IMgKzLgSzDqgkLrqkiLjXOmAXJS8kPK8nyFv82hjLuh61UXbTQrCmw3oU5VPtiiYEqS1yXqWY40qfB0spyvKCvIIA)